# How does this addition work (13+7=1130)?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

I found [this problem](http://9gag.com/gag/azVrZRj) on 9gag and I have no idea how to solve it.

Here is the question:

$13+7=1130$

$88+9=47$

$32+28=2530$

$10+999=1149$

$444+77=61$

$55+111=56$

$21+0=1221$

$7+22=39$

$33+5=38$

$123+45=???$

The puzzle says to think outside the box.

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Well, the ones' digits are all correct, so the answer probably ends in 8...

Comment: If possible I think it might be wise to source/link where you go this puzzle from if you just copied it.

Comment: Sure, http://9gag.com/gag/azVrZRj

Comment: Looking at your latest edit, is the answer supposed to have three digits?

Comment: @mmking no idea, but in the original post it has three interrogation signs.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but in the original the 1s and the kerning around them are odd.  $21+0=1221$ almost looks like $21+0=\lvert 22 \rvert$ to me.

Comment: i think it's slightly looking different in image(from you link). so it's better if you provide same image here

Comment: Ok, I did it. Although someone may want to take it down later.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You just have to be descriptive in your addition:

> `13 + 7 = one 1 one 3 + one 7 = 1113 + 17 = 1130` 
>  `88 + 9 = two 8 + one 9 = 28 + 19 = 47` 
>  `32 + 28 = one 3 one 2 + one 2 one 8 = 1312 + 1218 = 2530` 
>  `10 + 999 = one 1 one 0 + three 9 = 1110 + 39 = 1149` 
>  etc.

So the final solution is

> `123 + 45 = one 1 one 2 one 3 + one 4 one 5 = 111,213 + 1415 = 112,628`

Comment: +1 Nice! The sad thing is, in trying to figure this out last night, I thought of the "look-and-say numbers", as featured in [this Numberphile Youtube video featuring John Conway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ea7lJkEhytA), but I **still** didn't make the connection!

Comment: Wow... Well this solution just reminded me of another good puzzle I know... probably need to save it for a bit.